# Access main Object variables in prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have this Object

```
rsa = {
    publicKey: function(bits, n, e,r) {
        this.bits = bits;
        this.n = n;
        this.e = e;
        this.r = r;
    },
    generateKeys: function(bitlength) {
        var p, q, n, phi, e, d, r, keys = {}; //array vacidos de keys
        // if p and q are bitlength/2 long, n is then bitlength long
        this.bitlength = bitlength || 2048; //coge 2048 si no esta paso el bit length y si esta pasado coge valor bitlength
        console.log("Generating RSA keys of", this.bitlength, "bits");
        p = bignum.prime(this.bitlength / 2);
        do {
            q = bignum.prime(this.bitlength / 2 + 1);
        } while (q.cmp(p) === 0); //0 si p y q son identicoss
        n = p.mul(q);

        phi = p.sub(1).mul(q.sub(1));

        e = bignum(65537);
        d = e.invertm(phi);
        //random to blind
        var r = (bignum(2).rand(n));  
        keys.publicKey = new rsa.publicKey(this.bitlength, n, e, r); //genera una nueva public key
        keys.privateKey = new rsa.privateKey(p, q, d, keys.publicKey);//genera una nueva private key
        return keys; //return public and private key
    } 
};
```

Then I have these prototypes of the Object, how can I access the variables in the Object from the prototypes..

```
rsa.publicKey.prototype = {
    encrypt: function(m) {
        return m.powm(this.e, this.n);
    },
    verify: function(c) {
        return c.powm(this.e, this.n);
    },
    //blind message
     blind: function(m){
         var Men_encrypt = bignum(25);
        console.log("r en funtion" +this.r);
        var e
         this.e = e;
        console.log("e en funtion" +e);
        return Men_encrypt.mul((this.r).powm(this.e,this.n));

         };
```

When I try to access the variables in the main Object all I get is that they are "Underfined"

Comment: _When I tries to access the variables in the main_ - how?

Comment: @Maximus e.g from the blind () in the prototype-----> this.r (to get the this.r variable in the publicKey: function())

Comment: do you call it like this `rsa.publicKey.blind()` or `(new rsa.publicKey()).blind()` ?

Comment: I called it like this:   `rsa.publicKey.prototype.blind();`

Comment: in that case `blind` is called in the context of `rsa.publicKey.prototype` object which doesn't have `r` property. what you probably want is this `(new rsa.publicKey()).blind()` - it should be able to access `r`

Comment: @OlusegunOdumosu There is no "`this.r` inside a function". There only is an `r` property on an instance *object* such as `keys.publicKey`. You must call the method on that object, e.g. `keys.publicKey.blind()`

Comment: @Bergi I need the value of the r in the blind().

Comment: @OlusegunOdumosu There is no single r, no "the value". There are multiple instance with multiple `.r`s, and you need to call the `blind` method on the particular instance that you are interested in.

Comment: @OlusegunOdumosu, did you see my [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42738975/access-main-object-variables-in-prototype#comment72596217_42738975) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, you have the following:

```
rsa = {
    publicKey: function() {
        this.r = 5;
    }
}
```

To get access to the value `r`, you need to create an instance of `publicKey`, so:

```
let key = new rsa.publicKey();
k.r; // 5
```

Now, you want to have a `blind` method available on the instance of `rsa.publicKey`, so you need to set an object with `blind` method as a prototype of `rsa.publicKey` constructor. You do it like this:

```
rsa.publicKey.prototype = {
    blind() {
        console.log(this.r);
    }
}
```

And now you can call it like this:

```
let key = new rsa.publicKey();
key.blind(); // outputs 5
```

It ouputs `5` because  `this` inside `blind` refers to `key` object, since  `blind` is called as a method of `key` object. If you do like this:

```
rsa.publicKey.prototype.blind();
```

`this` refers to the `rsa.publicKey.prototype` object since `blind` is called as a method of `rsa.publicKey.prototype`, and it doesn't have `r` property.